# Mongoose; Save property which is not specified by a model

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Is it possible to save (update/insert) some property which is not being specified by a model with [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/)?

---

#### What I've tried

I have UserModel. Something like this:

```js
const UserModel: Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
});

export interface IUser extends Document {
    name: string;
}
```

and I've tried to append new property `{visible:true}` in `update` which is not specified by model.

```js
UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(data.user._id, {visible:true}, {new: true}, (err,res)=>{
    console.log(err,res);
})
```

and it **has not been updated** but it works if I specify `visible` in model.

```js
const UserModel: Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    visible: { type: Boolean, required: false, default: false },
});

export interface IUser extends Document {
    name: string;
    visible: boolean;
}
```

---

**How to save properties which are not specified by a model?**

Answer (score 2):

I've found [`strict`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#strict) option for [`Schema`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).

> The strict option, (enabled by default), ensures that values passed to our model constructor that were not specified in our schema do not get saved to the db.

Working solution looks like this:

```js
const UserModel: Schema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
}, { strict: false });
```